# Magento error Error log record number: 727685574651 in magento

Tags: magento-1.8

i am using magento 1.8 version. i have an error when order is placed in checkout page success.. 
Error log record number: 727685574651 in magento.

Answer (score 1):

Find the report inside your magento's folder installation "{magento_root_folder}/var/report".

A file is created named with the number presented in your screen, in this case "727685574651", open it with an text editor and check the issue.